# Converting object to date format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi i have a dataframe df with column trans_dt

I would like to convert this to date format for all rows. This is currently of object type

can someone help.

````
20    14022022
20    14022022
20    14022022
20    14022022
20    14022022
        ...   
20    14022022
20    14022022
20    14022022
20    14022022
20    14022022
Name: trans_dt, Length: 1939, dtype: object```
````

Comment: I tried it it dint work. As my variable is 14022022 so i think i need to first seperate the date, month, and year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) function, specifying a [format](https://strftime.org/) to match your data.

```
df['trans_dt'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['trans_dt'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Comment: thanks this works